# How can I prove this simple result?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ not symmetric matrix where all of its rows sums to zero. How can I show that the linear system $Ax = 0$ has infinite solutions and all of them are $x = k\cdot(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ for any $k$ real in a simple way?

Oh, I know that the matrix is singular and then has infinite solutions. I just want to know how to show that the solutions are x = k*(1, 1, ..., 1).

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't write "infinite solutions" if you mean "infinitely many solutions".  "Infinite solutions" means "solutions, each one of which, by itself, is infinite".

Comment: Did you meant *not* symmetric? Or *anti* symmetric ?

Comment: Not symmetric. Sorry, here in Brazil the translation from portuguese would be asymmetric.

Comment: You have been provided with several answers. Do you find any of them helpful? Do you need any clarifications?

Comment: Yes, they are helpful, but your answer let me with a doubt. I've just asked you something. It would be great to hear your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $$\pmatrix{-1&1&0\cr-1&1&0\cr-1&1&0\cr}$$ satisfies the hypothesis, but not the conclusion, since $x=(0,0,1)$ is in the nullspace.

EDIT: In case "asymmetric" was supposed to be "antisymmetric", then the zero matrix will serve as a counterexample.

Comment: This matrix is not anti symmetric

Comment: The question asks for the matrix to be "asymmetric". It does not say "antisymmetric".

Comment: But if you want an antisymmetric counterexample, just take the zero matrix.

Comment: I though asymmetric and anti symmetric is the same for matrices. My bad. Apologies.

Comment: @Dror, I never saw the word "asymmetric" used to describe a matrix before, so you may be right, but it's new to me.

Comment: Honestly neither did I. language-wise I think you are correct. But common sense tells me the OP meant anti symmetric. Let's find out.

Comment: The kernel of this matrix is two-dimensional, $x=(1,1,1)^T$ spans the second dimension.

Comment: @LutzL, what is your point? Of course $(1,1,1)$ is in the nullspace, but OP asked for it to span the nullspace, which it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry guys. I meant not symmetric. Asymmetric is literally the translation from portuguese to english. And I think I forgot to say that there is no column where all the elements are zero once all the diagonals elements are different from zero.

Comment: Then are you happy with my answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I'm sorry, I read it wrong. Instead of "is also in the nullspace" I interpreted it as "is the only direction in the nullspace". The first is obviously the correct interpretation and a very valid point.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, Well, actually it doesn't help me. I just want to proof that for my system the solution would be k*(1,1,...,1) only (and I really don't know if it is possible with my informations). Your assumption arises for assuming that a column could have all the elements zero (right?). Sorry if I'm not being clear, actually I'm start to study linear algebra now.

Comment: Numerically, if I perform the factorization all the results give me a row echelon form matrix that has the last row with all elements zero and all the rest o the matrix is a diagonal matrix with 1 at the diagonal and zero at the rest. So x1 = x2 = ... = xn-1 and xn = k (arbritary value). Well, the properties that this matrix holds are: all rows sums zero and there's no row or column that have all elements equals to zero. Well, it's possible to show that the "only" solution is k*(1,1, ...,1) with those informations? If no, there are some requiriments for that? It would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: The examples show that it is **not** necessarily the case that the only solutions are scalar multiples of the all-ones vector. This has nothing to do with an all-zero column; it's easy to make up examples where there are no zeros in the matrix at all. I encourage you to try to find some. Anyway, it seems to me that the question you asked has been comprehensively answered. If that means the question you asked isn't the question you really wanted answered, you can always post another question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ and since all of its rows sums to zero so
$$\forall i=1,\ldots,n,\quad \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=0$$
so if we denote
$$y=Ax$$
then
$$y_i=k\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=0$$
hence $$Ax=0$$
and there's no need for the hypothesis of the not symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

If the sum of each row is $0$, try considering the rows of $A^T$ as vectors $\vec{v}_n$.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n k\vec{v}_n = k \sum_{i=1}^n 1 \cdot\vec{v}_n = k \vec0 = \vec0$$
Can you continue from here?

Note that these are generally not *all* of the solutions, as Gerry Myerson pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ is a row vector, then the sum over the components of this row vector is equal to the product of $a$ with the column vector $(1,1,\dots,1)^T$.

By the assumptions that means that the matrix-vector product of the given matrix with this column vector is zero, i.e., this vector and all multiples of it are kernel vectors.